# Problems with php-cli and mysql, why is mysql_pconnect() not available?

Tags: php

I've installed various PHP packages to be able to use PHP with Apache but also in the commandline. From both I need to be able to connect to MySQL databases. Pretty simple right? That's what I thought but with php-cli I receive following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()
```

I have tried starting from scratch by removing all depending packages and configuration like this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-mysql
```

Then I've run following command to install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-mysql
```

Then I've found out which php.ini the cli uses like that:

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini
```

Which gives me this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Then i've uncommented 'mysql.so' in the extensions section but when i do and run following command it says:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

So for some reason he thinks it is already loaded, but with or without the 'mysql.so' enabled the php cli does not find the 'mysql_pconnect' function.

I know there's a sections to enable persistent connections, it on by default and the standard function 'mysql_connect' is also not available.

What am I missing? Thanks!

UPDATE:

As suggested by Bart S. 'php -r "phpinfo();" | grep mysql':

> ```
> MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
> MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql
> MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient
> mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
> ... and more
> ```

From Jaka Jančar. 'php -v' shows:

> PHP 5.1.2 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2009 19:55:22)

And from php interactive mode 'php -r 'var_dump(extension_loaded("mysql"));' gives nothing!

Comment: Does it say it list the MySQL modules when you execute phpinfo();?

Comment: @bart I've updated my question with some more info

Comment: Can you please do:
php -v
php -r 'var_dump(extension_loaded("mysql"));'

Comment: A newline missing after "php -v", of course.

Comment: @jaka Updated with your suggestion. var_dump returns nothing. txn.

Comment: It can't print nothing... it's either true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php -i | grep mysql
```

The first line should contain:

```
Configure Command =>  '../configure' ... '--with-mysql=shared,/usr'
```

Also check

```
grep extension_dir /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Should be something like: `extension_dir = /usr/lib/php5/extensions`
Then check permissions of `/usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysql.so` and if it's properly linked:

```
ldd  /usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysql.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use pconnect in CLI mode. You dont have a persistent process like the web server which can hold the open connection.

Answer (score -1):

Does pconnect in cli mode make sense? maybe this is "working as intended".

> Note: Note, that these kind of links
> only work if you are using a module
> version of PHP. See the Persistent
> Database Connections section for more
> information.

https://www.php.net/mysql_pconnect

Comment: mysql_connect doesn't work either. And i would think mysql_pconnect should work, but idd it does not make sense, i'm using the sphyder search engine cli scripts. and i'm using it exactly like docs tell me.